# Changing State in PlayerControler from PlayerInput

Tags: udk, unreal

In my player input I wanna change the the "State" of my player controller
but I have some trouble to do it

my player input is declared like that :

```
class ResistancePlayerInput extends PlayerInput within ResistancePlayerController
    config(ResistancePlayerInput);
```

and in my playerControler I have that :

```
class ResistancePlayerController extends GamePlayerController;

var name PreviousState;

DefaultProperties
{
    CameraClass = class 'ResistanceCamera' //Telling the player controller to use your custom camera script
    InputClass = class'ResistanceGame.ResistancePlayerInput'
    DefaultFOV = 90.f //Telling the player controller what the default field of view (FOV) should be
}

simulated event PostBeginPlay()
{
    Super.PostBeginPlay();
}

auto state Walking {
    event BeginState(name PreviousStateName) {
        Pawn.GroundSpeed = 200;
        `log("Player Walking");
    }
}

state Running extends Walking {
    event BeginState(name PreviousStateName) {
        Pawn.GroundSpeed = 350;
        `log("Player Running");
    }
}

state Sprinting extends Walking {
    event BeginState(name PreviousStateName) {
        Pawn.GroundSpeed = 800;
        `log("Player Sprinting");
    }
}
```

I have tried to use

`PCOwner.GotoState();` and  `ResistancePlayerController(PCOwner).GotoState();` but won't work.

I have also tried a simple GotoState, and nothing happen

how can I call GotoState for the PC Class from my player input ?

Comment: Are you in multiplayer or singleplayer? And I'm assuming you mean that you are using: `PCOwner.GotoState('Sprinting')`.

Comment: I'm in single player. But the first answer help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the player controller class trying to change state the code works as

```
 GoToState('Fleeing');
```

If in Pawn, what I have gotten to work is

```
Controller.GotoState('PlayerClimbing');
```

because you are in the controller state you don't need to repeat it.

Hope that helps.